# Boto3 EC2 instance filter with tag

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, boto3

I would like to use a variable collected as part of python script in the place of KEY in tag:key. I find no luck. Below is my code. But the value part works.

```
tag_key_f = input("Enter Tag Name to find: ")
tag_val_f = input("Enter Tag Value to find: ")
instances = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:tag_key_f', 'Values': [tag_val_f]}])
```

Comment: Come on guys. Please help...!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was fixed just by adding a separator.

```
tag_key_f = input("Enter Tag Name to find: ")
tag_val_f = input("Enter Tag Value to find: ")
instances = ec2.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name': 'tag:'+tag_key_f, 'Values': [tag_val_f]}])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import boto3

tag_key_name = "JobNumber" # replace it with your tag key name
values = ["Job123"]

client = boto3.client('ec2', aws_access_key_id=Config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, 

aws_secret_access_key=Config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)
instances = client.describe_instances(Filters=[{'Name': f'tag:{tag_key_name}', 'Values': values}])
```

This query worked for me to fetch the ec2 machines with a specific tag filter.